# Khan Academy - Factoring sum of squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I am working on [Precalculus - Factoring sum of squares](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:complex/x9e81a4f98389efdf:complex-id/v/factoring-sum-of-squares)

The video starts with example:

$36a^8 + 2b^6 = 6a^{4^{2}} + \sqrt{2}b^{3^{2}}$

Can someone explain this to me? What's happened here?

Thanks.

Comment: Notice that you have left out a critical part of the equation: the parentheses! It completely changes the meaning of the terms.

Comment: But to answer your question: Surely you understand that $36=6^2$ and $a^8 = \left(a^4 \right)^2$, right? And surely you also know that
$$
(xy)^2 = x^2 y^2
$$
, right?

Comment: Yes... They forgot to put the parenthesis (..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the video starts with
$$36a^8+2b^6=(6a^4)^2+(\sqrt{2}b^3)^2$$
which is of course true since $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ and $(a^n)^k=a^{nk}$